# Service Broker messaging which calls Web Service not ending

Tags: web-services, service-broker

I have a service broker message queue, each message calls a web service via a CLR stored procedure to do some processing

I have an issue where the conversation does not end, it works fine, everything it needs to do is done, it doesn't error, but the conversation never ends even though EndConversation is called.

It seems to be coming back from the web service call and calling EndConversation before the processing that the web service is doing has completed, and so the conversation does not end and the message is called again.

Is there anyway to stop the web service call coming back before it has completed so then the conversation in the message queue can end successfully.

I believe this is what is happening because if i cut out some of the work the web service call is doing so that it runs quicker than everything runs fine and the conversation ends.

I have also stepped through all of the steps happening in the web service call, and everything works, there are no errors etc.

Answer (score 0):

May need to see some of the code, especially the initiator. 
Are you using explicit transactions? 
Make sure you have a `COMMIT TRANSACTION` statement after `END CONVERSATION`.